# How to configure a TLS 1.2 Protocol in WebSphere 7.0.0.45 with Strong Cipher Suites?

Tags: java, websphere, tls1.2, java-6, sslhandshakeexception

I need to Configure TLSv1.2 in **WebSphere 7.0.0.45 (Java 1.6 SR 16 FP60)**. So I configured the Dynamic outbound configuration in WAS and Configured the SSL Configuration by following the steps in the links

https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/244958/how-do-i-configure-step-by-step-dynamic-outbound-e/

And I added the Custom property in Global Security and JVM Custom property

**com.ibm.websphere.ssl.include.ECCiphers = true**

After configuration I am able to Establish the connection with TLSv1.2 for

https://fancyssl.hboeck.de/ which only support TLSv1.2.

But I can't establish a connection for strong Cipher suite sites like

> TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0x003C)
>   TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x009C)
>   TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x009D)
>   TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0xC027)
>   TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (0xC028)
>   TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xC02F)
>   TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0xC030)

It's throwing an

> Fatal Error : Handshake Failure in ClientHello

I tried downloading the Unrestricted IBM Java policy files too. Still no luck

Please suggest me some best practice to configure TLSv1.2 in WAS7.0 and configure the Strong Cipher Suites to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I opened a PRM with IBM for the same problem. After several iterations, I have not been able to solve it yet.

IBM suggested to me to install the unrestricted policy file. After doing it I could install the ssl certificate doing a "Retrieve from port" from the was admin console. But the problem continue while trying to connect from the appl.

You may tray the same to see if it works for you following the steps here:
https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/178395/how-do-i-install-the-unrestricted-policy-files-in.html